# can i make a class diagram from an object diagram in UML ?

Tags: uml, software-design, class-diagram, object-diagram

as i know , an object diagram is a real case from a class diagram in UML , is it possible to draw a class diagram from an object diagram ? ( of course giving only the classes that appears on the object diagram ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure you can. However, the object diagram does not show attributes/operations and the links being association instances may also lack some information (multiplicity, role names). But for a raw class diagram it should give you a start.

Comment: Well, object diagrams can have attributes values if adds value to the purpose that the diagram pursues. Actually I add it most of the time.

Comment: @Joako-stackoverflow Yes, you can show attribute values. But still it's different to all attributes of a class (the type is not shown, only the name). And you will likely not who all attributes in any case on an object.

Comment: correct @thomas-kilian, just trying to add some more context

Comment: Sure. The same goes for my response ;-) (There's a typo in it: the last "who" should be "show".)